# Track a simple Firebase Event

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I want to track a simple Firebase event in my mobile game - When the player hits a score of 25, I want them to be labeled as an "active_player"

The code I got from my programmer looks like this, but it doesn't track in Firebase. Any thoughts of what could be wrong?

```
public void ReportScore(int score)
{
    Social.ReportScore(score, GPGSIds.leaderboard_total_icons,(bool success) => 
    {
        Debug.Log("Score reported: " + score);
        if (score == 25)
        {
            Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(
                Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventSelectContent,
                new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("active_player", score));                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to create an audience of players whose scores are above 25. What the code there does is log an `EventSelectContent` event with a parameter `"active_player"` whose value is `25`.

To [create an Audience](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en) of people who have logged that event with that parameter.

I don't think this is the best way to achieve your goal though. You can create your own events. For example, you could replace the above line with:

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("active_player");
```

at which point you could create an audience of everyone whose logged that event without diving into parameters.

But what I think you really should do is set [a user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/analytics/firebase-analytics#setuserproperty). This way you can easily categorize all the users who've achieved this goal. You could say something like:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty("gamertype", "active");
```

to mark a user as active.

Finally, I'm not sure what your overall goals are, but you may actually be better served by [Firebase Predictions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/predictions). A prediction that's automatically calculated for you is "churn" or "a user about to stop playing your game" or "not churn" which is basically your active player. Predictions do need more daily active users before they're active, but they have the potential of being the most beneficial if you're trying to take pre-emptive measures to retain your users. I think [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@lmoroney_40129/machine-learning-in-firebase-using-predictions-8a1df0c63b60) can shed more light on why you might choose predictions over just an analytics property.

Hopefully this helps!

--Patrick